# winforms detect change of focus within flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a flowlayoutpanel, and I'm adding a user specifcied number of custom controls to it at runtime.  What I want to do is detect when the flowlayoutpanel's children lose or change focus.

So, in other words, how can I tell when one child control loses focus?  I need to be able to see this at the flowlayoutpanel's form, so I can do some calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.LostFocus += new EventHandler(Control_LostFocus);
}

void Control_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control c = (Control)sender;
    //some code you want write for controls that lost focus
}
```

Comment: I like your version more, but I think Microsoft was deprecating `LostFocus` in favor of `Leave`.

Comment: @RedHat -Ok, I've got this running, but I'm getting way to many hits on the event.  I just want this event to fire once when a child control loses focus (collectively).

Comment: I check this now and work correctly, any of child control lost focus fired this event, right?

Comment: Yes, but I just got it fired 8 times, and I only have 2 controls.

Comment: when child control added?begin of application or dynamically added?

Comment: @RedHat -both.  I add 2 at the beginning, then add on button press.

Comment: @RedHat -I just want the event fired once.  I don't really care which of the panel's controls fire it, but I only need 1 to fire it.

Comment: check that flowLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded how many fired?Is it fired number of child control added?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5110/discussion-between-redhat-and-maw74656)